# When executing report part in Report Builder, The path of the item "~" is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long

Tags: reporting-services, report, filepath, reportbuilder3.0

All,

Recently ran into this issue while working on Report Parts for a client. I have a utility that creates report parts in batches based on information you provide to it. This includes the paths for the datasets and data sources.

After creating the Report Parts and the corresponding Data Sources (all were just tablixes based on the views) I tried to run them in report builder 3.0. I got this error:

`The path of the item '{Path to Report Part Here}' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long`

Answer (score 0):

At first I assumed that the path length was the issue, since it IS a long path. However it was only around 160 characters. Not even close. When you expand the error message, which is essential, you get this:

```
...; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, 
the path must start with slash.
```

This ended up being the issue. The person who ran the utility incorrectly eliminated the leading forward slash in the path to the data sets and data sources. Something along these lines is on MSDN, but I wanted to have it here as well.

My suggestion would be to open the xml files in Notepad ++ and replace the paths across all the files you have. You'll have to do this for both the report parts and their data sources as far as I know.